# Change percentage decimal precision in Woocommerce deposits plugin payment plan

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, formatting, precision

I'm using the Woocommerce Deposits plugin. It uses percentages to calculate the deposit and payment. I need the deposit and payment to be an exact amount. I can calculate the exact percentages to give the exact amount but the plugin does not allow decimal points for the percentages. It rounds up or down to a whole number.

Example: I need 28.3465% it will round down to 28%.

I used the code (below) which allowed me to add 2 decimal places. So 28.3465% would round off to 28.35%. I changed line 133 of class-wc-deposits-plans-admin.php from this:

```
$plan_amounts = array_map( 'absint', $_POST['plan_amount'] );
```

to this:

```
$plan_amounts = array_map( 'wc_format_decimal', $_POST['plan_amount'] );
```

Is there a function or some way to add 4 decimal points instead of 2?

I found this on woo's docs, but I can't figure it out.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/function-wc_format_decimal.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your **own custom formatting function** based on [`wc_format_decimal()` source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_format_decimal.html#280-317) that will handle **4 decimals** by default:

```
function wc_four_decimals( $number, $dp = 4 ) {
    $locale   = localeconv();
    $decimals = array( wc_get_price_decimal_separator(), $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['mon_decimal_point'] );

    // Remove locale from string.
    if ( ! is_float( $number ) ) {
        $number = str_replace( $decimals, '.', $number );
        $number = preg_replace( '/[^0-9\.,-]/', '', wc_clean( $number ) );
    }

    return number_format( floatval( $number ), $dp, '.', '' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme, or in a plugin file). Tested and works.

Then you will replace simply:

```
$plan_amounts = array_map( 'wc_format_decimal', $_POST['plan_amount'] );
```

by:

```
$plan_amounts = array_map( 'wc_four_decimals', $_POST['plan_amount'] );
```

---

**To change the decimal precision programmatically in Woocommerce** you can use the following hooked function, where you can add any condition *(the default value is set in Woocommerce genera settings)*:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', 'custom_decimals_precision'){
function custom_decimals_precision($dec){
    $dec = 4; // Four decimals precision

    return $dec; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been working on this all day. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried it and it is sort of working. It is showing the 4 decimal points but it is not letting me save it. 

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/6a16765e0342921ccbe454e6aa25ad17

Comment: @Krankit… In this answer, I have just replaced in your provided code, the woocommerce wc_format_decimal formatting function (2 décimals by default), by a similar custom one that has 4 decimals by default. The fact that it doesn't save the showed result is something else and you should need to alter some more code in that plugin, somewhere in the saving hooked function.

Comment: You could use: `add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', function($dec){ return 4; }`, but it will change the decimal precision to 4 everywhere in woocommerce including all plugins that uses wc_format_decimal funtion, so it will not be convenient for you.

Comment: Thanks again! This certainly gets me farther than I was and yes it works. I'm sure the not saving issue is with-in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to divide amount by 3 in equal parts. 390 / 3 = 130, sounds simple? Well not in this case. But I have tought the plugin division, with little hack in two places.
Works fine.

As percent in payment plan I specified parts: **33.3,33.3,33.4** as totals would account to 100 percent and then in code I replaced multiplication by division whenever I found "33.3" or "33.4".

**class-wc-deposits-scheduled-order-manager.php:65**

```
//ROUNDMOD -----------------------
                if (($schedule_row->amount == 33.3) or ($schedule_row->amount == 33.4)) {
                    $item['subtotal'] = round ( $line_price / 3, 2 );
                    $row_discount = round( ( $item['deposit_deferred_discount_ex_tax'] / $percent_remaining ) * 33.3333333, 2 );                    
                }
                //---------------------------------
```

**class-wc-deposits-product-manager:222**

```
if ( $percentage ) {
                $product_price = is_null( $product_price ) ? $product->get_price( 'edit' ) : $product_price;
                
                //ROUNDMOD -----------
                if (($amount == 33.3) or ($amount == 33.4)) {
                    $amount        =  round (($product_price / 3 ),2);
                } else {
                    $amount        = ( $product_price / 100 ) * $amount;
                }
                //--------------------
            }
```